# Templates on Django

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie on web dev and chose Django to start, in my application I need sign up and sign in freatures, searching i've found about django-registration:

[Link to repo](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/)

The setting file and url are already configured, but I have to make the templates for login - I got some templates for test - but I have no idea where to put it, if I have to create a new app ("... startnewapp registration") or just create a directory for templates somewhere. 
Can you help me?

Comment: In your settings.py file, you specified where to put template files ... inside that folder, create a folder, named it registration and put required html file as doc says.

Comment: you can use `bootstrap` and `modal class` to create a popup window for login or signup

Answer (score 3):

you dont really need an external app for just a registration. it is simply one urlconf and one view.

but the most important thing for you now is to go through [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/), because tutorial tells you what to put where exactly.. and this cannot be explained here in 3 lines of text

Answer (score 0):

Especially at the beginning it is very helpful to see an example where to put the things together. I developed a django-skeleton, which basically bootstraps a Django installation and boosts starting a new project. I also created views to use the builtin authentication module of Django for registration and to login: https://github.com/n2o/django-skeleton/

In this case I created a separate [login app](https://github.com/n2o/django-skeleton/tree/master/login) to modify the views and create my own templates.

This is not the easiest way to modify existing templates, but it fulfills all of my requirements.